# Login to Kubernetes container in a pod with multiple containers

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I can login to a single container pod following the guidance from

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/

with

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty $POD_API -- /bin/bash
```

where $POD_API=api-79c8g4948d-24vth [or whatever kubernetes assigns to it]

However, I have a pod with 2 containers on it [one the cloudsql proxy and the other an api].

How can I login to my api container? My api container is named: api and the cloudsql proxy is named cloudsql-proxy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-c` to choose a container

```
kubectl exec podname -c containername --stdin --tty -- /bin/bash
```

So in your case to login to api container

```
kubectl exec $POD_API -c api --stdin --tty -- /bin/bash
```

and to login to cloudsql proxy container

```
kubectl exec $POD_API -c cloudsql-proxy --stdin --tty -- /bin/bash
```